# Game crashing when game started

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to make a spaceship game, however, when I added the part which allows you to fire bullets, the game crashed immediately crashed when I run the game.

Here is my current code (Some parts omitted or replaced by --snip--)

```
class Spaceship(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, s, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.screen = s
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.image = pygame.image.load("C:/eqodqfe/spaceship.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (175, 175))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, s, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.screen = s
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.image = pygame.image.load("C:/eqodqfe/bullet.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (100, 100))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)

    def fire(self):
        while self.y <= 490:
            self.y -= 5


spaceship = Spaceship(screen, 400, 400)
bullet = Bullet(screen, 0, 0)

running = True
while running:
    --snip--

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_a]:
        spaceship.x -= 0.5
    elif key[pygame.K_d]:
        spaceship.x += 0.5
    --snip--

    spaceship.update()
    bullet.update()

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(spaceship.image, spaceship.rect)
    screen.blit(bullet.image, bullet.rect)

    bullet.x = spaceship.x
    bullet.y = spaceship.y-20

    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed():
        bullet.fire()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Does anybody know what went wrong?

Comment: What do you expect by `while self.y <= 490:` `self.y -= 5`? This is an infinite loop.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot to add self.kill() at the end. Will that fix it? (500 is max y)

Comment: No you have to remove the loop. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to make the bullet disappear when it hits the edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you expect by

> ```py
> while self.y <= 490:
>    self.y -= 5
> ```

This is an infinite loop.

To make a bullet you have to create an instance of `Bullet` when mouse button is pressed. However you have to use the `MOSUEBUTTONDOWN` event. [`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed) returns a list of Boolean values ​​that represent the state (`True` or `False`) of all mouse buttons. The state of a button is `True` as long as a button is held down. The `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event occurs once when you click the mouse button and the `MOUSEBUTTONUP` event occurs once when the mouse button is released.

Move an `kill` the bullet in `update`. `update` is continuously invoked in the application loop:

```py
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update(self):
        self.y -= 5
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)
        if self.y < 0:
            self.kill()
```

Create a `Bullet` when the `MOSUEBUTTONDOWN` occurs:

```py
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()

running = True
while running:
    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
       if event.type == MOSUEBUTTONDOWN
           bullet = Bullet(screen, spaceship.x, spaceship.y-20)
           bullets.add(bullet)

    bullets.update()

    # [...]
    
    bullets.draw()
    pygame.display.update()
```

---

See also:

- [How can i shoot a bullet with space bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59687250/how-can-i-shoot-a-bullet-with-space-bar/59689297#59689297)
- [How do I stop more than 1 bullet firing at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60122492/how-do-i-stop-more-than-1-bullet-firing-at-once/60125448#60125448)
- [Pygame: problems with shooting in Space Invaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65759929/pygame-problems-with-shooting-in-space-invaders/65759972#65759972)

Comment: Thanks for the help!