# TypeError: Source objects must be a surface

Tags: python, pygame

import pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, x, y, direction, rect):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.speed = 10
    self.image = bullet
    self.rect = rect
    self.rect.center = (x, y)
    self.direction  = direction
```

bullet_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

while gameRun:

```
clock.tick(FPS)

draw_bg()

enemy.draw()
enemy.update_animation()

player.update_animation()
player.draw()
player.move(move_left, move_right)

bullet_group.update()
bullet_group.draw(screen)

if player.alive: 
    if shoot:
        bullet = Bullet(player.rect.centerx, player.rect.centery, player.direction, bullerRect)
        bullet_group.add(bullet)
    if player.in_air:
        player.update_action(2)
    elif move_right or move_left:
        player.update_action(1)# 1 is run
    else:
        player.update_action(0)# 0 is idle

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        gameRun = False
    
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            move_left = True
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            move_right = True
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            shoot = True
        if event.key == pygame.K_w and player.alive:
            player.jump = True
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            move_left = False
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            move_right = False
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            shoot = False

pygame.display.update()
```

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\Users\gopal\Desktop\Misc Projects\main.py", line 136, in

```
  bullet_group.draw(SCREEN)
```

File "C:\Users\gopal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 546, in draw

```
 surface.blits((spr.image, spr.rect) for spr in sprites)
```

TypeError: Source objects must be a surface

Answer (score 0):

You have used the name `bullet` several times, but for different things. At the beginning it is a `pygame.Surface` object, but after adding the 1st bullet,

```py
bullet = Bullet(player.rect.centerx, player.rect.centery, player.direction, bullerRect)
```

it reference a `Bullet` object. Rename the variables.

Use the name `bullet_surf` for the image that represents the bullet:

```py
bullet_surf = pygame.image.load(...)
```

```py
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, direction, rect):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.speed = 10
        
        self.image = bullet_surf
```

---

To fire a bullet with the space bar see:

- [How can i shoot a bullet with space bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59687250/how-can-i-shoot-a-bullet-with-space-bar/59689297#59689297)
- [How do I stop more than 1 bullet firing at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60122492/how-do-i-stop-more-than-1-bullet-firing-at-once/60125448#60125448)
- [Pygame: problems with shooting in Space Invaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65759929/pygame-problems-with-shooting-in-space-invaders/65759972#65759972)